# Larave 6.x multidimensional arrays validation. old() function return empty array after validation

Tags: arrays, laravel-6, laravel-validation, laravel-session

I have [html-form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj19x.png) that contains arrays.
It has such structure:

```
"q" => array:1 [▼
  "new" => array:1 [▼
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "a"
      "v" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:1 [▼
          "text" => "b"
        ]
        2 => array:1 [▼
          "text" => "c"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I've created form request. And now it has one rule:

```
'q.new.*.v.*.text' => 'required|min:2|max:128'
```

And do you know what? Sometimes it works. When `q.new.*.v` array contains less than 4 elements everything validates just fine (I can see [error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRN97.png)). But when i send for example [such form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sck9j.png),
data is not flashed to storage and i can not retrieve it using `old()` function. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO2D2.png).
Some debug information:

```
[2020-02-06 22:37:51] local.INFO: Request all in form request: Array
(
    [q] => Array
        (
            [new] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => a
                            [v] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => b
                                        )

                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => c
                                        )

                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => d
                                        )

                                    [4] => Array
                                        (
                                            [text] => e
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
[2020-02-06 22:37:51] local.INFO: Old() in form request: Array
(
)
[2020-02-06 22:37:51] local.INFO: Old in controller after redirect: Array
(
)
[2020-02-06 22:37:51] local.INFO: Request all in controller after redirect: Array
(
)
```

I've tried to transform `q.new.*.v.*.text` into array of `q.new.1.v.1.text`, `q.new.1.v.2.text`, `q.new.1.v.3.text`, but that didn't give much results.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with default place of storing sessions. By default, SESSION_DRIVER is cookie (their size is limited). So I have changed driver to `file` and all worked in the right way.